# Format text to fit in columns in Excel

Tags: php, excel, csv

I have this block of text in an array:

```
"Stefan Olsson"
"Kungsvägen"
"Skolgatan"
xxxx-xx-xx
0735xxxxxx,
"Pär Davidsson"
"Skolgatan"
"Myntvägen"
xxxx-xx-xx
0709xxxxxx,
```

I parse this type of content to an CSV-file, for later usage in Excel. However, I want to fromat this text to fit in different columns in excell. So, when I open the CSV-file in Execel, I want the name to be in one column, the address in the column besides etcetc. How can I accomplish this? Should I use PHPExcel? Or could it be done with plain old PHP?

Here is my PHP-code

```
$gatunamn = $_POST['gata'];
$ort = $_POST['omrade'];
$csv_data = array();



$newSpider->fetchPage($gatunamn, $ort, $offset=0);
$obj = json_decode($newSpider->html);


echo "<div id='rightcontent'><table id='one-column-emphasis'>";
echo "<th><input type='checkbox' name='csv_all' id='csv_all'></th><th>Namn</th><th>Adress</th><th>Adress2</th><th>Adress3</th><th>Personnummer</th><th>Telefonnummer</th><th>Telefonnummer2</th>";
$antal_sidor = round($obj->search->wp->totalHits / $obj->search->wp->pageSize); 
echo "<td></td>";
foreach($obj->search->wp->features as $fish) //Loopar ut 50st (pageSize)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='csv' class='csv'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $fish->name . "</td>";
    $csv_data[] .= utf8_decode($fish->name);

    foreach($fish->addresses as $ad)
    {
        echo "<td>" . $ad->label . " " . $ad->postcode . " " . $ad->area . "</td>";
        $csv_data[] .= utf8_decode($ad->label . " " . $ad->postcode . " " . $ad->area);
    }   
    if(!empty($fish->dateOfBirth))
    {
        $convert_date = substr($fish->dateOfBirth, 0, -3); //Gör om datum från timestamp
        echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d", $convert_date) . "</td>";
        $convert_datee = date("Y-m-d", $convert_date);
        $csv_data[] .= $convert_datee;


    }
    if(!empty($fish->phoneNumbers))
    {
        foreach($fish->phoneNumbers as $ph)
        {
            echo "<td>" . $ph . "</td>";
            $csv_data[] .= $ph . ",";

        }
    }       

    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
$j = 0;
for($i = 1; $i <= $antal_sidor; $i++)
{
    echo  "<a href='curl2.php?gatunamn=$gatunamn&ort=$ort&offset=$j'>" . $i . "</a> ";
    $j += 100;
}
echo "</div>";
echo "<div id='debug'><pre>";   
    var_dump($csv_data);
echo "</pre></div>";

}
if(isset($_POST['export']))
{

    $fp = fopen("eniroo.csv","w");
    foreach(explode(",", implode("\n",$csv_data)) as $rad) {
       fputcsv($fp, array(implode(',', str_getcsv($rad, "\n"))));
    }
    echo "<div id='csv_info'>";
    echo "<a href='eniro.csv'>Hämta CSV-fil</a>";
    echo "</div>";


}
```

Comment: this can be done in php, but i think you forgot the desired output sample.

Comment: @kevinabelita: Desired outout sample? The output is shown above.

Comment: If all you want to do is write csv, then using PHP's built-in fputcsv() function is perfectly adequate; you only want to use PHPExcel if you want styling, or complex formulae, or multiple worksheets, or any of the other special features of MS Excel

Comment: But if this is one large block of text, you need to restructure it into an array; and that would apply whether you wanted to use PHPExcel or fputcsv()

Comment: @MarkBaker: I already have an array containing the text block.

Comment: Then what's your problem? Show a var_dump of your array, because what you are displaying is simply a block of text.... but it sounds as though you want that block of text writing to CSV, not the whole array

Comment: @MarkBaker: The problem I have is that I want to parse the text to csv-file in correct format, so the address, phonenumber etcetc gets into their own column in excel. HEre is my var_dump: http://pastebin.com/rPBUgvxW

Answer (score 0):

```
// Restructure the original array into rows
$myDataArray = array_chunk($myDataArray, 5);

// Then write to CSV
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach($myDataArray as $dataRow) {
    fputcsv($fh, $dataRow);
}
fclose($fh)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works quite well. But there is a problem. As you can see here: http://pastebin.com/B1WyW45t, the 2 first rows are correct, but the third is incorrect, because Bryan appears at the same row as Elin. It should be a new row with bryan instead. Any idea? The reason I think is that one person can have two adresses, which is 5columns, and one person may only have 1 adress, which results in only 4 columns.

Comment: Here is also a var_dump from my $dataRow: http://pastebin.com/KxtKq62k As you can see, Bryan are in the same section as Elin, which is wrong. How can I replace the 5th row with an empty string?

Comment: You probably want to walk your array before chunking, checking where an extra, empty entry needs inserting (ie there are only 4 entries for a record)

Comment: Yes, but how do I do this kind of check? I have no clue how to accomplish this check.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do this kind of check? I have no clue how to accomplish this check.